# Consume minimum N number of messages once from Kafka with KafkaListener

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I need to consumer minimum N number of messages once from Kafka with KafkaListener

Below are the Consumer configurations

```
Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "batch");
    // maximum records per poll
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, "10");
```

Comment: By KafkaListener, I assume you mean by Spring? Have you referred to the documentation on such capabilities?

Comment: Okay, but: where is [the rest of your question](/help/how-to-ask)? Remember that SO is not a general help forum, questions need to be more than just a few lines of code that do nothing on their own.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to guarantee the consumption of a minimum number of messages with spring-kafka. If you need to process the messages to perform a stateful operation, (either an aggregation, reduction ...) consider using kafka streams and maintain the advantages offered by kafka in terms of scalability, data consistency ...